# Trying to understand code in group project

Tags: bash

There is a section of code I cannot understand

```
base64 /dev/urandom | head -n 700 > NewFile.txt
```

I understand the `base64` is to encode binary to text, and `dev/urandom` is a random number generator. I also know the `head -n 700` is to display the first 700 lines of the file NewFile.txt. I cannot establish what the command will do together. Any direction is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Ask Ubuntu may not be the best place to get an answer to this question. You might try Stack Overflow, but be sure to review their question requirements carefully, otherwise search the web.

Comment: `>` replaces a file's content with whatever is on the left side of it; if the file (on the right side of it) does not exist yet, it creates the file too. So in effect the thing tries to base64 encode 700 lines of randomness, and puts it into newfile.txt.

Answer (score 2):

```
base64 /dev/urandom | head -n 700 > NewFile.txt
```

This command will write the output of your command into 'NewFile.txt'.

**Explaination:**

The ">" is used to route the output of an command to a file.

Eg.

```
echo "Hello There" > myFile.txt
```

Creates/Overwrites 'myFile.txt' in current working directory.

---

Similarly double ">",

```
echo "Hello There" >> myFile.txt
```

Creates/Appends 'myFile.txt' in current working directory.